# Constant Errors on SQL server, Event ID 28005 and 4625

Tags: security, sql

We have been getting the following errors on our SQL 2008 R2 server several times a second.

I have searched the internet to its ends and I cannot find a solution that will work in our situation.

I have found several solutions online, but most of them will not work in our environment because we do not control the User objects in our AD.

> **Log Name:**      Application
>
> **Source:**        MSSQL$SPSQL
>
> **Date:**          10/12/2012 7:33:33 AM
>
> **Event ID:**      28005
>
> **Task Category:** Server
>
> **Level:**         Error
>
> **Keywords:**      Classic
>
> **User:**          N/A
>
> **Computer:**    SQL Server
>
> > Description: An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the
> >     target queue. Error: 15404, State: 19. Could not obtain information
> >     about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN\USER', error code 0x5.
>
> **Log Name:**      Security
>
> **Source:**        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
>
> **Date:**          10/12/2012 7:35:26 AM
>
> **Event ID:**      4625
>
> **Task Category:** Logon
>
> **Level:**         Information
>
> **Keywords:**      Audit Failure
>
> **User:**          N/A
>
> **Computer:**     SQL Server
>
> **Description:** An account failed to log on.
>
> **Subject:**
>
> **Security ID:**  DOMAIN\SQL service account
>
> **Account Name:**  SQL service account
>
> **Account Domain:** Domain
>
> **Logon ID:**
>
> **Logon Type:** 3
>
> **Account For Which Logon Failed:**
>
> **Security ID:**  NULL SID
>
> **Account Name:**
>
> **Account Domain:**
>
> **Failure Information:**
>
> **Failure Reason:**
>
> Unknown user name or bad password.
>
> **Status:**  0xc000006d
>
> **Sub Status:**  0xc0000064
>
> **Process Information:**
>
> **Caller Process ID:** 0x5d4
>
> **Caller Process Name:** C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.SPSQL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
>
> **Network Information:**
>
> **Workstation Name:**
>
> SQL Server
>
> ### **Source Network Address:**
>
> **Source Port:**  -
>
> **Detailed Authentication Information:**
>
> **Logon Process:** Authz
>
> **Authentication Package:** Kerberos
>
> **Transited Services:-**
>
> **Package Name (NTLM only):-**
>
> **Key Length:**  0

Thanks!

Comment: Has the password for "DOMAIN\SQL service account" been changed or is the account locked in AD? Check the status of the account in AD and when the password changed last.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me this question belongs on SharePoint SE. This really seems like it's a SQL Server issue more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

can you check this out to see if this helps you :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlservicebroker/thread/28699c94-4d1b-43f2-bcfb-a95152ca226b/

> According to the error message you provided, you most likely have
>   connectivity issues to your Active Directory server - and the identity
>   of the owner of your databases  (dbo) is on that Active directory
>   server. The SQL Service Broker is causing this exception. If this is
>   not a resolvable issue condition, then you can change the owner to a
>   SQL login (e.g. sa) and this will resolve the exception.

You can do this with the following command on each database that has the wrong owner:

```
sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

above was taken from here:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/178/t/62024.aspx